# Most performant design for each member to manage his/her own news list?

Tags: mysql, database-design, php

Say a news website has news categories such as Politics, Business, Society, Education, Health, Tech, Celebrity, Lifestyle, ... etc. The number of categories may be more than 20. New categories may be added; existing categories may be deleted.

If a registered member has no desire to see the news of a certain categories, he/she should be able to block those news so that those news don't show up in the news list on the homepage. This will only affect himself/herself, of course. Other members have their own preferences.

Each member can visit the Manage News Categories page to block/unblock news categories. The page will contain a HTML `<form>` with `<input type="checkbox">`s of news categories.

What's the most performant database design for such a feature?

I'm currently not an expert of database design. My initial thought is creating an associative table called "member_category_map" and associate it with the "members" table and the "categories" table.

Not sure if I'm being naive, but I'm worrying that the "member_category_map" table might end up containing too much data. Assuming that there are 20 categories and each member only blocks 1 category. If there are 2,000,000 members, then the "member_category_map" would contain 2,000,000 * 19 = 38,000,000 data. I don't know if that's good for performance.

Advices are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need four tables:

```
User            Category           Article                  Pivot
+----+-----     +----+-------+     +----+--------+-----     +---------+--------+
| id | ...      | id | title |     | id | cat_id | ...      | user_id | cat_id |
+----+-----     +----+-------+     +----+--------+-----     +---------+--------+
```

Table `Pivot` is standing for M:N relation and contains the subscription pairs user:category. Each user can have 0..n categories subscribed and each category can be subscribed by 0..m users. To fetch articles accordingly to the user's subscriptions you need to use `JOIN`s like that:

```
SELECT u.name  AS UserName
     , c.title AS Category
     , a.id    AS ArticleID
     , a.title AS ArticleTitle
     , a.date  AS ArticleDate
     , a.url   AS ArticleLink
     -- everything you need 
  FROM user      AS u
  JOIN pivot     AS p  ON p.user_id = u.id     -- pivot to user first
  JOIN articles  AS a  ON a.cat_id = p.cat_id  -- articles and
  JOIN category  AS c  ON c.id = p.cat_id      -- categories to pivot then
 WHERE u.id = 12345
 ORDER BY a.date DESC
 LIMIT 10
;
```

For the best performance you need to index tables by the columns used by the query:
`user` should have the primary Key (id)
`article` should have the multicolumn key (id, cat_id, date)
`pivot` should have the multicolumn primary key (user_id, cat_id) with FKeys to the corresponding tables.

Comment: Thanks. You mentioned that `article` should have the multicolumn key.... I guess you mean "multicolumn primary key"? I don't quite understand why `article` needs  multicolumn primary key, since it already has id column (which can be the primary key). Could you please explain?

Comment: @IanY. Multiple columns from the `Article` table are looked up at the same time when query is performed. Some of them are looked up explicitly like `article.date` in the `WHERE` and some are looked up implicitly like `article.cat_id` in the `JOIN..ON` clause. The proper key should contain some/most/every column looked up during the query proceeding. Exact key is depend on the data cardinality/density/selectivity.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I now understand a bit more than before. Would you mind recommending a source/tutorial for further understanding this concept --> "The proper key should contain some/most/every column looked up during the query proceeding. Exact key is depend on the data cardinality/density/selectivity."?

Comment: Rick James collected a huge pile of the useful info and summarize it a lot. Refer to his page - http://mysql.rjweb.org/

Comment: Thanks for the resource! And also thank you for illustrating the table design with a useful query example. That really helps me understand why the tables/database are designed in that way :)

Answer (score 3):

My strongest suggestion is...

- Once you have a few thousand 'users', throw away the schema and start over.

Seriously.  After you have experience with *your* application, you can formulate more specific questions, hence get more specific answers.  And you will know what the pain points are.

I have gone through *similar* things in the past, I have written about them.  (Thanks to Kondybas for the mention.)

- Many:many tables are often inefficiently designed.  Specific tips for such:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
- You did not mention it (yet), but you probably want to "list the latest 10 articles about category X" or "... with tag T" or "... written by U".  When I was a novice, I watch that requirement sink a growing news site.  After it was too late, I came up with http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists
- And if you want the second page of 10 articles, you will probably learn the hard way that `OFFSET` is not efficient.  Spoiler alert:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination
- Avoid Entity-Attribute-Value:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav
- Normalize, but don't over-normalize.
- If you will be deleting old articles, use Partitioning; else don't be tempted by Partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint
- Think about the rest of the world:  Get utf8mb4 correctly in place *now*.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

If you follow those tips, you may be able to postpone the schema rewrite until after 10K users.

Comment: Thanks Rick. These guides really broaden my horizons :)